# Oracle SQL for Previous Year Data

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i write SQL which will fetch the data for current year -4

e.g. if i run this sql today so it should give me the data from 2014 to till date

if i run this sql in 2019 so it should give me the data from 2015 to till date

please assist.

Comment: Have you tried/searched anything?

Comment: Hint: `sysdate`, `trunc()`, `add_months()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `interval`

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn >= trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') - interval '4' year
AND yourcolumn <  trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy');
```

This will produce results from 2015/Jan/01 to till date; If you need exactly 4 years worth of data then you need to tweak this SQL to include date and month along with the year.

Comment: Glad it worked. You could follow the steps from here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers